# Google Docs Viewer terms of use

Tags: google-docs, google-docs-api

Can we use docs.google.com/viewer (or docs.google.com/gview) service to organize a preview of the files (doc, pdf etc) on our commercial web app? Or is there any other solution from Google Docs?

Comment: Did you find some information on this topic? We are also looking at google docs viewer, but not having terms/conditions with google about the usage is a nogo.

Comment: Unfortunately not. We continue to use it, because we didn't receive any complaints from Google.